# Error while running maven project via Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm getting the following error while trying to build my maven project in Jenkins.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.adf.plugin:ojmake:12.2.1-0-0:compile (default) on project TestApp: Execution default of goal com.oracle.adf.plugin:ojmake:12.2.1-0-0:compile failed: Unable to load the mojo 'compile' in the plugin 'com.oracle.adf.plugin:ojmake:12.2.1-0-0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: oracle/jdeveloper/deploy/maven/OjmakeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\test\pom.xml to com.test/test/3.7.2/TestApp-3.7.2.pom
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.oracle.adf.plugin:ojmake:12.2.1-0-0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/maven-repository/com/oracle/adf/plugin/ojmake/12.2.1-0-0/ojmake-12.2.1-0-0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/maven-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
```

Jenkins version : 2.19.2

Maven version : 3.3.9

jdk version : 1.7.0_79

I'm using maven compiler plugin in my pom.xml file, the target and source set is 1.7. I'm working in Windows Environment. Ensured that the PATH variable is set as required. However, still the Jenkins job fails. 
How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

**This seems to be a java mismatch.** 
Configure you're Jenkins Jobs to use **JDK 8**. 
It can be done under "*Manage Jenkins*" option or you can make it specific to job under "*configure*" option inside the jobs.

Comment: Installed Jdk8 and configured my Jenkins job to use this JDK version. Still getting error.                              `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.adf.plugin:ojmake:12.2.1-0-0:compile (default) on project TestAppView: Cannot run program "${env.ORACLE_HOME}/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojmake.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I can see that the java error has been disappeared, But now it seems to be a missing file issue
 
`Cannot run program "${env.ORACLE_HOME}/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojmake.exe"`

This line clearly states that a file named "ojmake.exe" is missing from the mentioned path 
i.e. **"${env.ORACLE_HOME}/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojmake.exe"**. 
So, please place the desired file (ojmake.exe) in that location. Lets check whether it executes further or not.
Fingers Crossed.

Answer (score 0):

The version number shown describes the version of the JRE the class file is compatible with.
Java SE 8 = 52
Might be you have a dependency that need java 1.8

Refernce - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by replacing the ojmake.exe with ojmake file in all the pom.xml files in the source code.

JDeveloper provides multiple types of ojmake files, check the type of file with Linux command 'file' and check if it is Linux executable.